# Drop down menu in CSS not working as should

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Anyone know why this wont work correctly? The dropdown should only appear when you hovet on the menu name but it appears if you hover below the item name and the longer the menu list the further beneath it you can hover to make it drop down. For example if you hover below the menu name "skills" the dropdown appears instead of only appearing when you click ON the name or hover over it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
$min-width: 120px; 
$secondarycolor: #CCFF00;
$thirdcolor: #000000; 

@mixin transform($value) { 
-webkit-transform: ($value); 
-moz-transform: ($value); 
-ms-transform: ($value); 
transform: ($value); 
} 

@mixin transition($value) { 
-webkit-transition: ($value);
 -moz-transition: ($value); 
-ms-transition: ($value); 
transition: ($value); 
} 

*{ 
box-sizing: border-box; 
}

 body { 
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color: #CCFF00;
background: #374954; 
text-align: center; 
} 

#main { 
position: relative; 
list-style: none; 
background-image: url('https://tc-boxing.com/pic/gradient.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x no-repeat-y; 
font-weight: 600; 
font-size: 0; 
text-transform: uppercase; 
display: inline-block; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 50px auto;
 li { 
font-size: 0.8rem; 
display: inline-block; 
position: relative;
 padding: 15px 20px; 
cursor: pointer; 
z-index: 5; 
min-width: $min-width; 
} 
}

 li { 
margin: 0; 
} 

.drop { 
overflow: hidden; 
list-style: none; 
position: absolute; 
padding: 0; 
width: 100%;
 left: 0; 
top: 48px; 
div { 
@include transform(translate(0,-100%)); 
@include transition(all 0.5s 0.1s); 
position: relative; 
}

 li { 
display:block;
 padding: 0; 
width: 100%; 
background-image: url('https://tc-boxing.net/pic/gradientdd2.png') !important;
background-repeat: repeat-x no-repeat-y;
 }
 } 

#marker { 
height: 6px; 
background: $secondarycolor !important;
position: absolute;
 bottom: 0; 
width: $min-width; 
z-index: 2; @include transition(all 0.35s); 
} 

@for $i from 1 through 4 { 
#main li:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
&:hover ul div { 
@include transform(translate(0,0)); 
} 
&:hover ~ #marker { 
@include transform(translate(#{(-1+$i)*$min-width},0));
 } 
}
 } 
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #374954;
  color: #CCFF00;
  text-align: center;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  background-image: url('https://tc-boxing.com/pic/gradient.png');
  background-repeat: repeat-x no-repeat-y; 
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#main li {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 5;
  min-width: 120px;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
}

.drop {
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 48px;
}
.drop div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.5s 0.1s;
  position: relative;
}
.drop li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://tc-boxing.net/pic/gradientdd.png') !important;
  background-repeat: repeat-x no-repeat-y;
}

#marker {
  height: 4px;
  background: #CCFF00 !important;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 120px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

#main li:nth-child(1):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#main li:nth-child(1):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  transform: translate(0px, 0);
}

#main li:nth-child(2):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#main li:nth-child(2):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(120px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(120px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(120px, 0);
  transform: translate(120px, 0);
}

#main li:nth-child(3):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#main li:nth-child(3):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(240px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(240px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(240px, 0);
  transform: translate(240px, 0);
}

#main li:nth-child(4):hover ul div {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
#main li:nth-child(4):hover ~ #marker {
  -webkit-transform: translate(360px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(360px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(360px, 0);
  transform: translate(360px, 0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- not responsive yet -->
<nav>
  <ul id="main">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Skills
      <ul class="drop">
        <div>
        <li>scss</li>
        <li>jquery</li>
        <li>html</li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <div id="marker"></div>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/dghez/pen/Kwoper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding::

```
#main li {
 visibility: hidden;
}

#main li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
```